# Use stack of member variable?

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop

In general is it better (for performance) to use stack variables or temporary member variables?

I have a function that is being called in "real time" and there are a number temporary variables (of various data types) that are required. Is it better to just use stack variables (i.e. in function) or to use private member variables in the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are only needed inside the method, keep them in the method as local method variables. This isn't primarily a speed concern (although a "ldloc" is presumably less effort than a "ldarg0, ldfld" combination) - but rather: scope: it reduces the **size** of the object, and also allows for re-entrancy without confusion.

Note also: not all local method variables go on the stack ;p

Comment: "Note also: not all local method variables go on the stack ;p" really? I wasn't aware of that. I knew that allocated data is in the heap but I thought that all local variables/references to heap were in the stack. When is this not the case?

Comment: @Lea captured variables (lambdas, anonymous methods), and iterator blocks; they are implemented as fields on a compiler-generated class

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling is that stack variables would be faster, but this is a real micro-optimization.  You would have to profile it to be sure.

Comment: Agree, just profil it. But before doing it: Check if your really need to optimize, else take the easiest way and optimize later.

Comment: @Tarion I have implemented done this with local variables, the function just looked a little cluttered that was all. If this was likely to be of concern I was willing to switch to private member variables. But as this is probably not the case then I will just stick to the local variables for the time being. Cheers